# Passing parameter with AuthContext.Provider in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, jsx

I  am trying to pass paramater(username) with AuthContext.Provider in React js, but in another component I got this value as undefined. I check the value inside first component with console.log and I get username but when I pass I got undefined. So where it can be mistake?

```
render() {
    const value = {
      authUser: this.state.authUser,
      username: this.state.username,
      authErr: this.state.authErr,
      logout: this.logout
    }
    console.log(this.state.authUser +"username");
    if (this.state.submitted && this.state.authErr === null) {
      return <Redirect to='/teacher/portal'/>;
    } 
    return (

<AuthContext.Provider value={value}>

    {console.log(this.state.username + "username")}
    
      <div className="Login">

        <Form method="POST" onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event, this.login)}>
          <Nav.Link href="/student">Login as Student</Nav.Link>
          <h2 class="text-center">Teacher Log in</h2>

          <Form.Group controlId="username">
            <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              name="username"
              placeholder="Username"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={(ev) => this.onChangeUsername(ev)}
              required/>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId="password">
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={(ev) => this.onChangePassword(ev)}
              required/>
          </Form.Group>
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Login</Button>
        </Form>


        {this.state.authErr !==null && 
                            <Alert variant= "danger">
                                {this.state.authErr}
                            </Alert>
                            }


      </div>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
```

and I try to get value with value.username inside this component inside AuthContext.Consumer

```
   return (
        <AuthContext.Consumer>
          {value => (
      <div className="teacherP">
        <div className="nav">
          <Navbar>
            <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
              <Navbar.Brand >
                <Navbar.Text>
                  Course Name:
                  <a>Web Development</a>
                </Navbar.Text>
              </Navbar.Brand>

              
            </Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav className="ml-md-auto">
            {/* {context.authUser && 
            <> */}


              <Navbar.Brand>Welcome {value.username} !</Navbar.Brand> 
              {console.log(JSON.stringify(value.username) + " username")}

              <Nav.Link onClick = {() => {value.logout()}}>Logout</Nav.Link>
            {/* </>} */}
          <Nav.Link href="#">
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
          </Navbar>
        </div>

        <Card
          style={{
          width: '22rem',
          float: "left",
          margin: "50px"
        }}>
          <Card.Img variant="top"/>

          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Create an exam and a schedule</Card.Title>
            <Button margin="5px" variant="primary">Create</Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>

        </div>
         )}
 </AuthContext.Consumer>     
    );
```

Comment: Is your `Consumer` component wrapped under the `Provider` component?

Comment: if you mean it is parrent component, yes

Comment: I mean the component you're using `AuthProvider.Consumer` should be inside your `Auth.Provider`